# rsession: no process found - R Studio

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, rstudio, rstudio-server

I am installing R Studio on AWS ec2 instance running Ubuntu. While installation I get an error "rsession: no process found". 
After installation I opened "server_ip:8787" in browser, R Studio asked me for login credentials. I am unable to login as it always shows "RStudio initialization error : Unable to connect to server".

In terminal when I enter `sudo rstudio-server verify-installation` nothing happens.

`sudo rstudio-server restart` gives `rsession: no process found`.

I also tried `sudo ufw allow 8787` but no success.

Answer (score 1):

you've probably already fix your issue, but have you actually installed R BEFORE RStudio?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (using Hetzner server) and `sudo ufw allow 8787` did the trick for me. Thanks!